# Learning 32-bit assembly

Tags: winapi, assembly, 32-bit

I want to learn 32-bit assembly. I got some programming background, mostly high-level languages but also 16-bit ASM.

I want to write real simple console applications for Windows (I remember something vague about some difference between Windows and Linux, maybe just when creating graphical applications?).

Any ideas where to start?

Comment: Overlapping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360279/learning-assembly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [recommended guides/books to read assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059944/recommended-guides-books-to-read-assembly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [Randy Hyde](http://homepage.mac.com/randyhyde/webster.cs.ucr.edu/index.html)'s work, especially [*The Art of Assembly*](http://homepage.mac.com/randyhyde/webster.cs.ucr.edu/www.artofasm.com/index.html).  You will want the Windows 32-bit edition.

Answer (score 1):

This is the starting point: http://www.masm32.com/

There you will find an SDK with compiler, libraries, and **samples**. Enjoy!