# recommended guides/books to read assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, reverse-engineering

So lately I've been intrested in reading assembly which is displayed by a disassembler like ollydbg. The reason why I want to read this assembly is to learn how other developers build their applications or things like file formats of binary files the program has.

It's not like I'm a complete newbie at programming since I've been using C++ and C# for a while now. And I have a solid understanding of C++ so the whole pointer concept is clear to me.

Well I know that there are tons of assembly guides out there on the internet but I have no idea how reliable they are this tutorial: http://jakash3.wordpress.com/2010/04/24/x86-assembly-a-crash-course-tutorial-i/ was very usefull too me and this is the kind of tutorial with just a short explanation of the instruction. This one was very clear to me but it doesn't cover all of the assembly codes.

I hope someone could give a good guide/tutorial.

Comment: Not a guide, but you will want to download [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/) and the info from [here](http://www.agner.org/optimize/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good beginners' books for Assembly languages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199679/good-beginners-books-for-assembly-languages)

Answer (score 4):

I think the standard guide to assembly is [The Art of Assembly](http://homepage.mac.com/randyhyde/webster.cs.ucr.edu/www.artofasm.com/Windows/HTML/AoATOC.html). It's online and free.

Comment: This is my favorite book, too.

Comment: Randall "Randy" Hyde's [forward](http://homepage.mac.com/randyhyde/webster.cs.ucr.edu/www.artofasm.com/Windows/HTML/Foreword.html#47) and [editorial at ACM Ubiquity](http://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1513451) (open access) should also be read by anyone interested in learning assembly language, regardless of whether they use his textbook (AoA) for learning assembly language. IMO

Comment: The above link doesn't work; found an alternative at http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/index.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are interesed in x86 assembly and the opcodes for all instructions, try the [Intel manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/) (free download). If you want to know how to program in assembler, use the [recommendation by Seth Carnegie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059944/recommended-guides-books-to-read-assembly/7059952#7059952). Another download would be the [32 bit edition](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCEQFjAB&url=http://portal.aauj.edu/portal_resources/downloads/programming/assembly_language32bit_edition.pdf&rct=j&q=the%20art%20of%20assembly%20language%20pdf&ei=C0VITorjCIPJsgbP6qmjCQ&usg=AFQjCNHaX0_axe0s4kgubKm2kpwdRbHILw&sig2=MnYJCimHqUbaug70j-XU-g&cad=rjt).

Comment: +1 since the OP wanted reliability. For that it is best to go straight to the original source, in this case Intel.

Answer (score 1):

I learned much of what I know about assembly language from Matt Pietrek's [Just Enough Assembly Language to Get By](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0298/hood0298.aspx) and [its sequel](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0698/hood0698.aspx). This is especially made for C or C++ programmers wanting to read what the compiler emits in their debugger.

Pietrek's material is above any doubt and he writes clear and entertaining. It's tailored to the Windows platform, though.

Comment: And it is really just the minimum to get by. <g>

Comment: @Rudy: Of course it is. But it's most of what you need when you need to delve into assembly debugging to understand a problem in some C or C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach.  I recently released a first draft of learning assembly by example.  It is not x86 assembly though, on purpose.  Learning a better and easier to understand instruction set first, will get you through the basic concepts, from there other instruction sets, x86 included are often a matter of downloading an instruction set reference for the desired processor.  https://github.com/dwelch67/lsasim

Normally googling xyz instruction set will get you a number of hits (instead of xyz choose the one you are interested in, arm, avr, 6502, etc).  Ideally you want the vendors documentation which is usually free.  There have been so many variations on the x86 by different companies that it adds to the mess.  There are a lot of good online references though.  For other families, msp430, avr, arm, mips, pic, etc, you can often go to the (core processor) vendors site to find a good reference.   msp430, arm and thumb are also good first time instruction sets if you are not interested in the lsa thing.  mips or dlx as well so I am told unfortunately I have not learned those yet.  avr and x86 after you have learned something else first.  Pic has a few flavors, the non-mips traditional pic instruction set is certainly educational in its simplicity and approach, might be a stepping stone to x86 (I dont necessarily recommend pic as a first instruction set either).  I recommend learning a couple of non-x86 instruction sets first.  And I recommend learning the 8088/86 instructions first, I can give you an ISBN number for the original intel manuals, can probably be found for a few bucks at a used book store (online).  Lots of websites have the x86 instruction set defined as well, I highly recommend a visible simulator first before trying on hardware, will make life easier...qemu for example is not very visible nor easy to make visible. gdb's simulators might be as you can at least step and dump things out.

Answer (score 0):

I really liked Programming From the Ground Up, a free book which aims to teach you the basics of ASM programming in a pretty easy to understand way. You can check it out here:

[Programming from the Ground up](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pgubook/)