# Tutorials / books on understanding assembly output

Tags: c++, c, assembly

There are times when understanding disassemblies from higher languages such as C or C++ are useful. Reading a book on assembly is obviously a necessary part of understanding compiler output, but in my experience writing assembly code from scratch is quite a different thing than reading and understanding the opcodes a compiler produces. The books i know on assembly don't cover that part very well, altough I believe if you ever get in touch with assembly then mostly by trying to understand compiler output.

Do you know good in-depth tutorials (or maybe books) on how to interpret compiler output?

What I have in mind would be a presentation of common high language idioms and how they are translated to assembly by common compilers (msvc and gcc).

Comment: i think you want to interpret MZ exe file. so search mz exe in google and follow the wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many similar questions here on SO:

- [Learning Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360279/learning-assembly)
- [Resources for learning ARM assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270078/resources-for-learning-arm-assembly)
- [Good x86 assembly book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845/good-x86-assembly-book)

Most posters aim to the same thing as you, that is read assembly code and not write new one.

Answer (score 2):

Everything[*] I know about reading x86 assembly, I learned by single-stepping in a debugger in disassembly view. It's useful to have an opcode reference open at the same time, but to be honest you can live without most of the time, because as long as the compiler isn't optimizing too much, you know what it's actually doing from the C source, contents of variables, etc.

[*] Well, most things.

Comment: this is how I learned too, the only assembly 'books' I've ever read are the instruction set and optimization manuals from AMD and intel. IMO this route give you far more than any book or 2 second tutorial, on many levels

Comment: @Necrolis: you've put in more effort that me: I can't *write* x86 assembly if my life depended on it. But if all you need it for is to figure out what the optimizer has done this time, that doesn't matter.

Comment: Everything* I learned about assembly I learned from programming machine code on a TRS-80 Model 1 when I was a kid. :)

Comment: @Necrolis:  Can you provide a link to the Intel optimization manual?  I'm very interested to see this.

Comment: funnily enough I never learn with the intention of programming in assembly, but since I did, I've been saved many a time, most recently would be the use of 64bit CAS on x86 on older VC compilers :) @John: sure, here are all the manuals: http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/ and the optimization one specifically: http://www.intel.com/design/pentiumii/manuals/245127.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could compile some c,c++ files and keep the assembler output (option -s I think) and compare the generated output to your source files.

This should help you to understand the generated assembler code and recognize repeating patterns (method/function  calls, returns, loops, initialization etc.). Do not enable optimization this would transform the generated code and make it harder to understand.

Comment: I've done extensive experimentation with teaching this method in the past (see http://opensolaris.org/os/community/documentation/files/book.pdf sorry shameless plug) and must suggest: _DO_ use optimization. Just not the highest level. This is because unoptimized assembler code is full of unnecessary operations ... slightly-optimized code is far easier to read.

Comment: @FrankH: I find that the compiler plays a bigger part than the actual optimization level, MSVC outputs very readable code at both endds of the optimization spectrum, at least from my perspective, where as GCC generated code seems quite cluttered with tons of direct stack access, maybe I'm just not setting the optimization level correctly on GCC :P