# Is assembly language helpful for a fortran programmer?

Tags: assembly, fortran

I am under the impression that knowledge of assembly language can be beneficial to any high level programmer because it helps them to understand how computers really work and thus write high level code more intelligently.

I feel tempted to start learning assembly language for this reason alone but I am also wondering whether it would be useful for me, as a fortran programmer, to actually be able to write assembly language.

Could I find myself rewriting simple fortran procedures in assembly language in order to better solve scientific problems?

Apologies if this question has been answered elsewhere.

Comment: It is always helpful to know more, imho... ;) I don't think it will really help to write scientific programs faster, but it might help to optimize such programs, even without actually writing stuff in assembly, which I'd think would be a rather bad idea in most circumstances.

Comment: There is a question [Learning Assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360279/learning-assembly?rq=1) already asked, you might want to peruse the answers. Note that with gfortran, you can type `gfortran -S codename.f90` and get the assembly output so you can see how your code compares to hand-writing it.

Comment: I think you make a reasonable argument for learning how to read assembly language. As for hand-crafting tight, fast, memory-efficient numeric assembler to replace the offerings of a Fortran compiler ... well I've just described some of the better implementations of BLAS (*etc*). Could you find yourself writing assembly language routines to beat those ?  Tough nut to crack.

Comment: I doubt that you will find assembly language useful for solving scientific / numeric problems.  Modern compilers are so good that you will be hard pressed to beat them.  Occasionally assembly might be useful in device drivers and OS, though C is more frequently used.  Understanding more about how computers work might be beneficial.

Answer (score -1):

I am actually surprised how many programmers think they should learn assembly or even try it before they master some higher level language. 
There are scenarios where assembly is required (system level programming, toolchain programming (backends), really tiny embedded CPUs), but other than that it's not really that useful (anymore).

For your purpose you should probably learn how CPUs do calculations (to be able to better organize data & algorithms), maybe check some architectural details of your CPU, etc. Agner Fog has written [a bunch of optimization manuals](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#manuals)  (available for free). 
Being able to read assembly, to check the code compiler has generated, can be helpful, but is not absolute requirement.

I assume you already enough about parallelization (and [GPGPU]) if you want to speed up your scientific algorithms[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units)?

Comment: Learning some assembly is different than mastering it. For most people having some understanding of assembly, at least being able to read and understand simple examples, will be helpful regardless of what high level language they use.